# no conversion operator for string class

Tags: c++, stl

I am reading about STL string class. It is mentioned as below

STL string class chooses not to define conversion operators, but rather use the c_str() and data() methods for directly accessing the memory. The STL purposely does not include implicit conversion operators to prevent misuse of raw string pointers.

My question is

1. c_str() returns const char* pointer and still user can modify string value. Am I right?
2. What does the author mean by "to prevent misuse of raw string pointers"? Please explain, preferably with an example.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. what do you think the `const` means?

Comment: 1. You can modify the string, but **not** via the pointer returned by `c_str()` or `data()`. 2. Modifying the contents of the underlying string data without maintaining invariants. For example, by modifying via the pointer returned by `c_str()` or `data()`.

Comment: ... http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlIsNotTheCppStandardLibrary

Comment: @StoryTeller Even standard library implementation maintainers refer to it as STL. The term simply changed its meaning over time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, well, they are wrong :P

Comment: @StoryTeller Let me repeat: “The term simply changed its meaning over time.” It happens. I assume you refer to that machine you’re working on as “computer”. According to you, that’s wrong since “computer” originally meant something different.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, no, I prefer to say "machine". And according to me it's wrong to say "STL" and mean the c++ standard library. Your'e extrapolating rather far. Regardless, I reckon we took this OT enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use the return value of `std::string::c_str()` to
modify the string.  Trying to do so is undefined behavior.  And
the problem was (and still is) the lifetime of the pointer
returned by `std::string::c_str()`.  It becomes invalid if the
string is destructed, or if any non-const function is called on
the string.  The issues are things like:

```
char const* s = string1 + string2;
//  s is invalid here.
```

vs.

```
char const* s = (string1 + string2).c_str();
//  s is invalid here.
```

In the first case, it's easy to make the mistake, without
realizing it, so the committee decided to not have implicit
conversion, so that this would be illegal.  In the second case,
you have to really want to.